# Stop, and stop now

Tags: riddle, word, poetry

> Oh hang thee, I do, from the rafters above;
>   Though I'll often do my utmost to support thee from below.
>   Sometimes I'm wont to leave thee waiting in ears;
>   But as a rule, I'm a beast, telling thee to stop, and stop now.

What am I?

**Hint 1:**

> Line 2: think modern-day technology; Line 4: generic application of the word.

**Hint 2:**

> Line 1: another generic application of the word (by this I mean close to its definition); Line 3: for the musically-inclined.

**Hint 3:**

> Three-syllable word starting with S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you

> Suspension?

Oh hang thee, I do, from the rafters above;

> Suspending something from a height or rafters

Though I'll often do my utmost to support thee from below.

> Like a suspension bridge or suspension (ie. tires and a suspension system supporting a car)

Sometimes I'm wont to leave thee waiting in ears;

> a means of creating tension by prolonging a consonant note while the underlying harmony changes, normally on a strong beat, from music theory

But as a rule, I'm a beast, telling thee to stop, and stop now.

> Either getting suspended for one’s actions, or being told to suspend operations immediately

Comment: That's it, nice job! I was thinking rot13(pne fhfcrafvba) for line 2.

Answer (score 2):

Final Answer

> Elevator

Because
Oh hang thee, I do, from the rafters above;

> An elevator's pulley is fastened above the highest point, so from the rafters is a logical spot

Though I'll often do my utmost to support thee from below.

> The elevator has a floor which supports people from below

Sometimes I'm wont to leave thee waiting in ears;

> We often wait for the elevator to finish stopping, usually waiting for some sort of sound, ie, a final clunk or a ding.

But as a rule, I'm a beast, telling thee to stop, and stop now.

> When an elevator stops, you stop going down or up, as it acts as a part of the floor you are now on.

First Answer

> Smoke Alarm

Comment: Hmm, I like that second answer, fits relatively nicely. But unfortunately it's not the intended answer...I'll add a hint in response